# Conditional compilation based on proc_macro

Tags: rust

Is it possible to somehow detect in a crate that it's used in proc_macro and include some items based on that?

Let's say I have a `token_parser` crate with a `Token` enum:

```rust
pub struct Group;
pub struct Ident;
pub struct Punct;
pub struct Literal;

pub enum Token {
    Group(Group),
    Ident(Ident),
    Punct(Punct),
    Literal(Literal)
}
```

It's intended to be a wrapper for a `proc_macro::TokenTree`, so I want to be able to use it inside a `proc_macro` crates. I don't want to manualy implement a converting logic in every crate, so I want something like this:

```rust
#[cfg(proc_macro)]
impl From<proc_macro::TokenTree> for Token {
    fn from(token: proc_macro::TokenTree) -> Self
    {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

while still having an option to use `token_parser` crate in normal crates.

P.S I'm aware of `proc_macro2` crate. I will probably use it (or even `syn`) in the end, for now I'm just trying to understand how to do something like that myself properly.

Comment: From a quick look at the `proc_macro2` source, have you tried [`#[cfg(use_proc_macro)]`](https://github.com/dtolnay/proc-macro2/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L226)?

Comment: Nevermind, it appears that's just activated by a feature. You'll probably need to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are primarily two ways I would reach for based on how I want to enable such functionality.

1. `feature` for project-based enabling

If you want it only available when opted for, that's a fantastic case to use a [cargo feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html). Crates that want to use such functionality can then choose to enable this feature while other crates can choose to not enable the feature. Whether this feature should be [`default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#the-default-feature) typically depends on how the library author believes it should/is used most of the time.

2. `cfg` for platform-based enabling

As you may have seen from reading the `proc_macro2` source, they conditionally enable a `cfg` in their [`build script`](https://github.com/dtolnay/proc-macro2/blob/f633e3106c2cf107925c25e56165d1105020fb14/build.rs#L126-L134)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html)</sup>. On the `wasm32` platform target it is disabled, otherwise it is enabled. This way is very useful in cases where enabling functionality mostly depends on the platform.

Comment: It was also not obvious to me that to use `proc_macro` mod types in non-`proc_macro` crate, I have to manualy include dependency for it.

`#[cfg(feature = "proc_macro")] extern crate proc_macro;`

Now at least my `bin` crate does get compiled and run. CLion get confused though, telling me that there is no `from<proc_macro::TokenTree>`  for `Token` type, even though I used a feature in a dependency.

Comment: If it's not a default feature, then CLion won't pick it up automatically. There is a per-project config in Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Rust > External Linters > Additional Arguments that allows you to enable one or more features when linting. You can either add specific features with `--features foo,bar` where `foo` and `bar` are features you want enabled for the linter. It is also common to test all features and all targets if suitable for the project, with the options `--all-targets --all-features`.